# Problem with SharedPreferences - how to use?

Tags: java, android

I'm making an app with a counter that rises when I tap an ImageView. That works, but now I want to save the counter to a SharedPreferences Object.

I've tried to initialize the SP Object inside the onCreate method, which obviously doesn't work. When I try to use sp.getInt(...) globally, it doesn't work either.
I understand why there is a problem (Trying to get an Integer from a sp object before it gets initialized), but I don't know how to solve it.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int counterint;
    TextView counter;
    String stringnumber;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.hugelon", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sharedPreferences.getInt("hugcounter", 0);
    }


    public void hughim(View view){

        counter = findViewById(R.id.countertv);

        stringnumber = counter.getText().toString();
        counterint = Integer.parseInt(stringnumber);
        counterint++;
        counter.setText(Integer.toString(counterint));

        sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("hugcounter", counterint);

    }

}
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.hugelon/com.example.hugelon.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.SharedPreferences
>   android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)'
>   on a null object reference
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'android.content.SharedPreferences
>   android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)'
>   on a null object reference

Comment: follow this answer to save and retrieve data from sharedpreference:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56966388/how-to-keep-sharedpreferences-values-when-android-app-killed/56966681#56966681

Comment: "I've tried to initialize the SP Object inside the onCreate method, which obviously doesn't work." – Sure it does. It won't work where you have it now. What problem did you have when you did it in `onCreate()`?

Comment: @MikeM. When I initialize it inside the onCreate Method, the sp.edit() inside the hughim Method turns red and says "Cannot resolve symbol sharedPreferences"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giovanni's answer is correct, you are just not setting the initial value at oncreate

```
      public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

            int counterint;
            TextView counter;
            String stringnumber;
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    counter = findViewById(R.id.countertv);
        sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.hugelon", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                stringnumber=String.valueOf(sharedPreferences.getInt("hugcounter", 0));
counter.setText(stringnumber);
            }


            public void hughim(View view){

                counter = findViewById(R.id.countertv);

                stringnumber = counter.getText().toString();
                counterint = Integer.parseInt(stringnumber);
                counterint++;
                counter.setText(Integer.toString(counterint));

                sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("hugcounter", counterint);

            }

        }
```

Comment: It flags ".toString()" inside the oncreate as "cannot resolve method"...

Comment: Now there is no error, thanks. But how do I set the saved Value into my counterint and into my TextView? I've tried to set it inside the oncreate, but it gives me an appcrash and a "TextView refers to a null object" error.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works now just as it's supposed to! Now I'm gonna study the code to learn how it exactly works so that I know it for the next time.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `getSharedPreferences()` before the `Activity` is actually created. You need to initialize the `SharedPreferences` in `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.hugelon", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); // Here, this is initialized AFTER super.onCreate
    ...
}
```

`Activity` extends from `Context` and the `Context` is needed by `SharedPreferences`. I suggest you to read about the Android Activity Lifecycle here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

To proof that the value actually is being saved, you can try the following code to test the saved value:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.hugelon", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); // Here, this is initialized AFTER super.onCreate

    int storedValue = sharedPreferences.getInt("hugcounter", 0);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Saved value: " + storedValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

And, don't forget to store the value by calling `apply()`:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putInt("hugcounter", counterint);
editor.apply();
```

Comment: I've tried this, but the int isn't saved then. When I restart the app, the TextView says 0 again.

Comment: You are retrieving the value from `sharedPreferences.getInt("hugcounter", 0);`, but you are not showing/assigning it to any visible variable. You need to show it in some `TextView`. E.g. `int storedValue = sharedPreferences.getInt("hugcounter", 0);`, then show `storedValue`.

Comment: I added some example for you.

Comment: This works as far as the Toast shows me the value of the last counter value when I killed the app. But how do I give this value to my counterint and to my TextView "counter" in oncreate?

Answer (score 1):

SharedPreferences requires an activity reference before it can be initialized, that's the purpose of the `this` in:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.hugelon", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

The problem with your code is that `this` is null at the time you are initializing your SharedPreferences object. The reason for this is that `this` gets initialized at `onCreate()`. Therefore, a fast solution would be to move the initialization of your SharedPreferences object inside onCreate. Here's a snippet of how your class would look afterwards:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int counterint;
TextView counter;
String stringnumber;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.hugelon", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    sharedPreferences.getInt("hugcounter", 0);
  }

}
```

## Addendum:

Put the value of `sharedPreferences.getInt("hugcounter", 0)` inside  a variable like this:

```
int myValue = sharedPreferences.getInt("hugcounter", 0);
```

I hope this helps. Merry coding!

Answer (score 0):

1. Initialize the SharedPreference in onCreate method
2. You tried to putInt in SharedPreference but didn't save it as you need to call

   ```
   sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("hugcounter", counterint).apply()
   ```

   OR

   ```
   sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("hugcounter", counterint).commit()
   ```

for that purpose. So use `commit()` or `apply()` to save in local storage.

Check the document [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()) about `apply()` method